# null objc class data for 'l67551' in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-mlkit

I am using FirebaseMLVisionTextModel document text detection. I get this error in Xcode 15 beta 4 and iOS 17 beta 3. [Compile time Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsjku.png). The same code works fine in Xcode 14 and iOS lower versions.

Please help me resolve the issue.

I also tried excluding arm64 but no luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem here and solve it adding "-ld64" to my Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags.

Here was where I found this "solution".
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11516